# showing coverage of functional tests without blind spots

Tags: go

I have a production golang code and functional tests for it written not in golang. Functional tests run compiled binary. Very simplified version of my production code is here: `main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())
    for {
        i := rand.Int()
        fmt.Println(i)
        if i%3 == 0 {
            os.Exit(0)
        }
        if i%2 == 0 {
            os.Exit(1)
        }
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}
```

I want to build coverage profile for my functional tests. In order to do it I add `main_test.go` file with content:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "testing"
)

var exitCode int

func Test_main(t *testing.T) {
    go main()
    exitCode = <-exitCh
}

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    m.Run()
    // can exit because cover profile is already written
    os.Exit(exitCode)
}
```

And modify `main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

var exitCh chan int = make(chan int)

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())
    for {
        i := rand.Int()
        fmt.Println(i)
        if i%3 == 0 {
            exit(0)
        }
        if i%2 == 0 {
            fmt.Println("status 1")
            exit(1)
        }
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}

func exit(code int) {
    if flag.Lookup("test.coverprofile") != nil {
        exitCh <- code
        runtime.Goexit()
    } else {
        os.Exit(code)
    }
}
```

Then I build coverage binary:

```
go test -c -coverpkg=.  -o myProgram
```

Then my functional tests run this coverage binary, like this:

```
./myProgram -test.coverprofile=/tmp/profile
6507374435908599516
PASS
coverage: 64.3% of statements in .
```

And I build HTML output showing coverage:

```
$ go tool cover -html /tmp/profile -o /tmp/profile.html
$ open /tmp/profile.html
```

[image: html coverage profile]

### Problem

Method `exit` will never show 100% coverage because of condition `if flag.Lookup("test.coverprofile") != nil`.  So line `os.Exit(code)` is kinda blind spot for my coverage results, although, in fact, functional tests go on this line and this line should be shown as green.

On the other hand, if I remove condition `if flag.Lookup("test.coverprofile") != nil`, the line `os.Exit(code)` will terminate my binary without building coverage profile.

**How** to rewrite `exit()` and maybe `main_test.go` to show coverage **without blind spots**?

The first solution that comes into mind is `time.Sleep()`:

```
func exit(code int) {
        exitCh <- code
        time.Sleep(time.Second) // wait some time to let coverprofile be written
        os.Exit(code)
    }
}
```

But it's not very good because will cause production code slow down before exit.

Comment: May I ask what the intended purpose or benefit of reaching 100% and all green is? What is not good if one line is not colored green? If this is for non-technical management: Just color the offending line green by postprocessing the cover report.

Comment: @Volker It's not fatal to have one line not green. I just don't want to cut corners. Post processing sounds good if no other alternative exists.

Comment: Run you test a few time and i get different results every time. this coverage report is on a specific run not over the whole thing. first time i get 70+/- % then 80% etc.

Comment: @dmportella because the app uses random numbers; if you remove random numbers, the result should be the same every time you run it

Comment: erm your tests shouldnt have to cover everything, I wouldnt do any post processing that sounds like cheating. what are you gaining or trying to do with this setup?

Comment: the point of my question was: how to show in coverage results that line `os.Exit(code)` is covered. But I realized that doing that without postprocessing is not possible. Imagine `os.Exit(code)` becomes green, it means app executed it, but it means it exits immediately without building coverage profile. So we will never see this line green in coverage results even if my functional tests cover this line.

Comment: @MaximYefremov yes that is correct. with your current tests it will never be run and never go green

Comment: @MaximYefremov I agree that the reason the line is not covered is because the progra exist. Did you try to add a time delay before exiting? Maybe so the coverage have the time to complete.

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini nah the coverage will never hit that line, because it is random everytime.

Comment: @MaximYefremovI resolved this issue ... i will post it soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per our conversation in the comments our coverage profile will never include that line of code because it will never be executed.

With out seeing your full code it is hard to come up with a proper solutions however there a few things you can do to increase the coverage with out sacrificing too much.

## func Main and TestMain

Standard practice for `GOLANG` is to avoid testing the main application entry point so most professionals extract as much functionality into other classes so they can be easily tested.

`GOLANG` testing framework allows you to test your application with out the main function but in it place you can use the TestMain func which can be used to test where the code needs to be run on the main thread. Below is a small exert from [GOLANG Testing](https://golang.org/pkg/testing).

> It is sometimes necessary for a test program to do extra setup or teardown before or after testing. It is also sometimes necessary for a test to control which code runs on the `main` thread. To support these and other cases, if a test file contains a function: `func TestMain(m *testing.M)`

Check [GOLANG Testing](https://golang.org/pkg/testing) for more information.

### Working example

Below is an example (with 93.3% coverage that we will make it 100%) that tests all the functionality of your code. I made a few changes to your design because it did not lend itself very well for testing but the functionality still the same.

package main

> dofunc.go

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

var seed int64 = time.Now().UTC().UnixNano()

func doFunc() int {
    rand.Seed(seed)
    var code int
    for {
        i := rand.Int()
        fmt.Println(i)
        if i%3 == 0 {
            code = 0
            break
        }
        if i%2 == 0 {
            fmt.Println("status 1")
            code = 1
            break
        }
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
    return code
}
```

> dofunc_test.go

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
    "flag"
    "os"
)

var exitCode int

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    flag.Parse()
    code := m.Run()
    os.Exit(code)
}

func TestDoFuncErrorCodeZero(t *testing.T) {
    seed = 2

    if code:= doFunc(); code != 0 {
        t.Fail()
    }
}

func TestDoFuncErrorCodeOne(t *testing.T) {
    seed = 3

    if code:= doFunc(); code != 1 {
        t.Fail()
    }
}
```

> main.go

```
package main

import "os"

func main() {
    os.Exit(doFunc());
}
```

### Running the tests

If we build our application with the cover profile.

> `$ go test -c -coverpkg=. -o example`

And run it.

> `$ ./example -test.coverprofile=/tmp/profile`

Running the tests

```
1543039099823358511
2444694468985893231
6640668014774057861
6019456696934794384
status 1
PASS
coverage: 93.3% of statements in .
```

So we see that we got 93% coverage we know that is because we don't have any test coverage for `main` to fix this we could write some tests for it (not a very good idea) since the code has `os.Exit` or we can refactor it so it is super simple with very little functionality we can exclude it from our tests.

To exclude the `main.go` file from the coverage reports we can use build `tags` by placing tag comment at the first line of the `main.go` file.

> `//+build !test`

For more information about build flags check this link: http://dave.cheney.net/2013/10/12/how-to-use-conditional-compilation-with-the-go-build-tool

This will tell `GOLANG` that the file should be included in the build process where the tag build is present but`NOT` where the tag test is present.

See full code.

```
//+build !test

package main

import "os"

func main() {
    os.Exit(doFunc());
}
```

We need need to build the the coverage application slightly different.

> `$ go test -c -coverpkg=. -o example -tags test`

Running it would be the same.

> `$ ./example -test.coverprofile=/tmp/profile`

We get the report below.

```
1543039099823358511
2444694468985893231
6640668014774057861
6019456696934794384
status 1
PASS
coverage: 100.0% of statements in .
```

We can now build the coverage html out.

> `$ go tool cover -html /tmp/profile -o /tmp/profile.html`

[image: Coverage HTML Report]

Comment: I am using exactly your code but have `coverage: 93.3% of statements in .` anyway. Looks like `//+build !test` and `-tags test` are not working. I tried with `go 1.7.1` and `go 1.6.2`. What version of `go` do you have?

Comment: @MaximYefremov here is the result of `go version` `go version go1.7 linux/amd64`

Comment: @MaximYefremov for more information look up: http://dave.cheney.net/2013/10/12/how-to-use-conditional-compilation-with-the-go-build-tool

Comment: thanks for the link. To make it work I have to add empty line between lines `// +build !test` and `package main`

Comment: ah yeah i forgot about that when i pasted it in. I have added the empty line to the example now

Answer (score 0):

In my [pkglint project](https://github.com/rillig/pkglint/tree/v5.7.16/cmd/pkglint) I have declared a package-visible variable:

```
var exit = os.Exit
```

In the code that sets up the test, I overwrite it with a test-specific function, and when tearing down a test, I reset it back to os.Exit.

This is a simple and pragmatic solution that works well for me, for at least a year of extensive testing. I get 100% branch coverage because there is no branch involved at all.