# How to mock a gin.Context?

Tags: go, testing, mocking, go-gin

Hi I've been trying to mock a gin.Context but I have not been able to make it work
I was trying what they did in this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41742988/make-mock-gin-context-in-golang) but it does not work with my router this is the error I have been getting

`r.POST("/urls", urlRepo.CreateUrl)`

`cannot use urlRepo.CreateUrl (value of type func(c controllers.Icontext)) as gin.HandlerFunc value in argument to r.POSTcompilerIncompatibleAssign`

This is the interface I created to later mock and the method in which I will be testing

```
type Icontext interface {
  BindJSON(obj interface{}) error
  JSON(code int, obj interface{})
  AbortWithStatus(code int)
  AbortWithStatusJSON(code int, jsonObj interface{})
```

}

```
func (repository *UrlRepo) CreateUrl(c Icontext) {
    var url models.Url
    c.BindJSON(&url)
    if !validators.IsCreateJsonCorrect(url) {
        c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": "Error format in Short or Full"})
        return
    }
    err := repository.reposito.CreateUrl(repository.Db, &url)
    if err != nil {
        c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": err})
        return
    }
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, url)
}
```

Instead of

```
func (repository *UrlRepo) CreateUrl(c Icontext)
```

it was

```
func (repository *UrlRepo) CreateUrl(c *gin.Context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you can't "mock" a `*gin.Context` in a meaningful way, because it's a `struct` with unexported fields and methods.

Furthermore, you can't pass to `r.POST()` a function whose type is not a `gin.HandlerFunc`, defined as `func(*gin.Context)`. The type of your handler `CreateUrl(c Icontext)` simply doesn't match.

If your goal is to unit test a Gin handler, you definitely don't have to mock the `*gin.Context`. What you should do is to set test values into it. For that, you can simply use `gin.CreateTestContext()` and manually init some of it fields. More info  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66952761/how-to-unit-test-a-go-gin-handler-function/66953599#66953599).

If for some other reason, your goal is to provide an alternate implementation of a functionality of `*gin.Context` for use inside your handler, what you can do is define your own type with your own alternative methods and embed the `*gin.Context` in it.

In practice:

```
type MyGinContext struct {
    *gin.Context
}

func (m *MyGinContext) BindJSON(obj interface{}) error {
    fmt.Println("my own BindJSON")
    return m.Context.BindJSON(obj) // or entirely alternative implementation
}

// Using the appropriate function signature now
func (repository *UrlRepo) CreateUrl(c *gin.Context) {
    myCtx := &MyGinContext{c}

    var url models.Url
    _ = myCtx.BindJSON(&url) // will also print "my own BindJSON"
    // ...

    // other gin.Context methods are promoted and available on MyGinContext
    myCtx.Status(200)
}
```

But honestly I'm not sure why you would want to override some methods of the `*gin.Context`. If you want to provide different binding logic, or even different rendering, you can implement the interfaces that are already exposed by the library. For example:

*Implement a binding:*

`c.ShouldBindWith()` takes as second parameter an interface `binding.Binding` which you can implement:

```
type MyBinder struct {
}

func (m *MyBinder) Name() string {
    return "foo"
}

func (m *MyBinder) Bind(*http.Request, interface{}) error {
    // stuff
    return nil
}

func MyHandler(c *gin.Context) {
   var foo struct{/*fields*/}
   c.ShouldBindWith(&foo, &MyBinder{})
}
```

*Implement a renderer:*

```
type MyRenderer struct {
}

type Render interface {
func (m *MyRenderer) Render(http.ResponseWriter) error {
    // ...
    return nil
}

func (m *MyRenderer) WriteContentType(w http.ResponseWriter) {
    header := w.Header()
    if val := header["Content-Type"]; len(val) == 0 {
        header["Content-Type"] = "application/foo+bar"
    }
}

func MyHandler(c *gin.Context) {
   c.Render(200, &MyRenderer{})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `gin-gonic` as your http router, the param for your entry point should be a `*gin.Context`.

So, for instance, you should be replacing this:

```
func (repository *UrlRepo) CreateUrl(c Icontext) {
```

With this

```
func (repository *UrlRepo) CreateUrl(c *gin.Context) {
```

This way you should be able to use a mock gin context as a parameter for your unit test

Comment: Yeah, you are right but how can I mock the methods of gin.context, like, BindJSON, JSON, etc

Comment: you could try using this approach:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57733801/how-to-set-mock-gin-context-for-bindjson