# Is it possible to mock a function imported from a package?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go, mocking

I have the following method to test, which uses a function imported from a package.

```
import x.y.z

func abc() {
    ...
    v := z.SomeFunc()
    ... 
}
```

Is it possible to mock `SomeFunc()` in Go?

Comment: Yes. Just assign `v` to your mock and use `v` instead of `z.SomeFunc`. Probably you would want to make `v` a global (and rename to `zSomeFunc`.

Comment: Thanks Volker!!!

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Yes, with a simple refactoring. Create a `zSomeFunc` variable of function type, initialized with `z.SomeFunc`, and have your package call that instead of `z.SomeFunc()`:

```
var zSomeFunc = z.SomeFunc

func abc() {
    // ...
    v := zSomeFunc()
    // ...
}
```

In tests you may assign another function to `zSomeFunc`, one that is defined in tests, and does whatever the test wants it to.

For example:

```
func TestAbc(t *testing.T) {
    // Save current function and restore at the end:
    old := zSomeFunc
    defer func() { zSomeFunc = old }()

    zSomeFunc = func() int {
        // This will be called, do whatever you want to,
        // return whatever you want to
        return 1
    }

    // Call the tested function
    abc()

    // Check expected behavior
}
```

See related / possible duplicate:
[Testing os.Exit scenarios in Go with coverage information (coveralls.io/Goveralls)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40615641/testing-os-exit-scenarios-in-go-with-coverage-information-coveralls-io-goverall/40801733#40801733)

Comment: How to mock if the function returns more than one value?

Comment: @user4002112 The same way. Obviously the function used for mocking has to return multiple values too.

Comment: Doesn't it have race condition problem when we run tests concurrently?

Comment: This is essentially global state. May work for something trivial, but may just as probably cause serious pain to someone who inherits such code (i.e several hours lost debugging). This is not a good pattern in a professional setting.

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин I would agree if the variable's value would be changed during the lifetime of the app. But it is not, its sole purpose is to aid testing, and its value is only changed in tests, so this use does not fall under the global state category.

Comment: I had to debug a case like that last week.  The test failed when run with all other tests, but passed when run in isolation. Global state means any variable or symbol that's globally available and can change (it was changed by other tests), including func-vars. It's literally the definition of global state.

Answer (score 12):

One thing you can do is this:

```
import "x/y/z"

var someFunc = z.SomeFunc

func abc() {
    ...
    v := someFunc()
    ... 
}
```

And in your test file you would do this.

```
func Test_abc() {
    someFunc = mockFunc
    abc()
}
```

But make sure that you do this in a concurrent manner, if you have multiple `TestXxx` functions calling `abc` or setting `someFunc` you may be better of using a `struct` with a `someFunc` field.

Comment: Worth noting, you can use the argument `-p 1` to `go test` to force all tests to run in series rather than parallel.

Comment: This is essentially global state. May work for something trivial, but may just as probably cause serious pain to someone who inherits such code (i.e several hours lost debugging). This is not a good pattern in a professional setting.

Comment: @Kaedys For this answer the default flag `go test -parallel 1` does make sense. The `-p 1` is however _not_ a synonym for that! The former is goroutine-level, the latter the pid-level.

Answer (score 5):

Having function pointer and monkey patching it is the one of doing it. But then when you multiple functions to mock, you will have a number function pointers and unnecessarily you will have to call function using the function pointer only.

The better and the recommended idea to have an interface and make your function part of the struct implementing the interface. Once done that, you can generate mocks using some nice tools available for go.

I have been using this:

```
mockgen -source myModule.go -package myPackage -destination myModuleMock.go
```

You can install it by:

```
go get github.com/golang/mock
```

Comment: gmock is excellent but does not have a native solution for global functions. you have to wrap them with an interface.

Comment: This article https://dev.to/jonfriesen/mocking-dependencies-in-go-1h4d explains the steps with examples for this approach.

Answer (score 2):

While creating a package level variable is a viable option, it comes with some restrictions. to name a few:

1. It discourages running parallel tests using `t.Parallel()` as there can be race conditions on different behaviors of mocked function.
2. it is dangerous as a future developer in the same package can accidentally update the implementation of this global variable.

another way is to pass along the methods you want to mock as arguments to the function to enable testability. In my case, I already had numerous clients calling this method and thus, I wanted to avoid violating the existing contracts. so, I ended up creating a wrapped function.

eg:

```
import (
 z "x.y.z"
)

//this should replicate the type of function z from x.y.z
type operation func() resp

func wrappedAbc(op operation) {
  ....
  resp := op()
  ....
}

func Abc() {
  wrappedAbc(z)
}
```

now for testing the actual logic, you will test calls to `wrappedAbc` instead of `abc` and you would pass it a mocked `operation`. this will allow you to test all the business logic while not violating API contract with current clients of method `Abc`.

Answer (score 1):

`mockcompose` uses an approach that allows you to generate a mocking class, you can direct `mockcompose` to include your selected dependency closure (any imported functions from other packages). In the mean time, it generates a cloned copy of your subject function with local overrides so that you can test against. You can embed code generation process with `go generate`, therefore ensure your cloned copy is always in-sync with your code changes.

Say you have a function `functionThatUsesGlobalFunction` that imports
`Sprintf` in package `fmt`.

```golang
func functionThatUsesGlobalFunction(
    format string,
    args ...interface{},
) string {
    //
    // skip fansy logic...
    //

    // call out to a global function in fmt package
    return fmt.Sprintf(format, args...)
}
```

Your goal is to test `functionThatUsesGlobalFunction` with `Sprintf` in package `fmt` being mocked.

To do that, you can configure `go generate` with `mockcompose` as following:

mocks.go

```golang
//go:generate mockcompose -n mockFmt -p fmt -mock Sprintf
//go:generate mockcompose -n mockJson -p encoding/json -mock Marshal
//go:generate mockcompose -n clonedFuncs -real "functionThatUsesGlobalFunction,fmt=fmtMock"
package clonefn
```

`go generate mockcompose` will then generate plumbing classes for you, enable you to write test code as following:

```golang
package clonefn

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/mock"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/require"
)

var fmtMock *mockFmt = &mockFmt{}

func TestClonedFuncs(t *testing.T) {
    assert := require.New(t)

    // setup function mocks
    fmtMock.On("Sprintf", mock.Anything, mock.Anything).Return("mocked Sprintf")

    // inside functionThatUsesMultileGlobalFunctions: fmt.Sprintf is mocked
    assert.True(functionThatUsesGlobalFunction_clone("format", "value") == "mocked Sprintf")
}
```

Please checkout [this](https://github.com/kelveny/mockcompose) for details.

Comment: This looked promising but I'm not finding it easy to use.  Just fighting mockcompose errors all the way, trying to mock [rabbitmq](https://github.com/rabbitmq/amqp091-go) `amqp.Dial`.