# Mocking methods from package

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking

I am looking to mock some methods for unit testing. Unfortunately, the code is not structured really well.

```
var config = struct { abc *abc }

func Init(arg1) {
    // config.abc = newAbc(arg2, arg3)
}   

func UnitTestThis() { 
    //some code here 

    config.abc.Search(arg4,arg5) 

    //code here 
}
```

How do I unit test the UnitTestThis function, mocking the results of Search method? I have been trying to create an interface and mock the methods, but been unable to do so.

Comment: Unable to do so *why*? What is the actual problem you're having?

Answer (score 1):

If the `config.abc` field is a concrete type (or a pointer to a concrete type), you can't really mock it.

You need some refactoring.

### With interface

Best would be to change the type of `config.abc` to interface type, so in tests you can create your own implementation and assign to it, and you can do whatever you want to in it.

### Using a method value on `config.abc.Search`

Another option is to create a variable of function type to hold the [method value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values) of `config.abc.Search()`, and in tests assign a new value to it, a [function literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_literals) for example.

This is how it could look like:

```
var config = struct{ abc *abc }{}

var searchFunc func(arg4Type, arg5Type)

func Init(arg1) {
    config.abc = newAbc(arg2,arg3)
    searchFunc = config.abc.Search
}

func UnitTestThis() {
    //some code here
    searchFunc(arg4, arg5)
    //code here
}
```

Read more about this here: [Is it possible to mock a function imported from a package in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42952191/is-it-possible-to-mock-a-function-imported-from-a-package-in-golang/42952311#42952311)

Comment: Can searchFunc be a reciever? If so, what would this syntax look like?

Comment: @GyanendraSingh I don't understand the question.

Comment: var searchFunc func(arg2Type, arg3Type) -> how would it look like for a reciever, along with definition?

Comment: @GyanendraSingh I still don't understand. `searchFunc` is a variable of function type, and `Init()` initializes it with a method value which implicitly stores the receiver value.

Comment: Thanks icza! I was able to set up the tests using function variable. However, this is problematic in the sense that it makes it open to abuse/bugs, if assigned to some other function matching the definition. I will try to set up the same using interfaces.

Comment: Also, config.abc is a struct.