# Mocking constructors in main func

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing, design-patterns, mocking

I would like to find a better way to mock my constructor. The constructor itself already returns an interface, thanks to which I can mock its functions in tests.

```
//main.go
var createSSMClient = ssm.CreateClient // my constructor

func main() {
    _, _, _ = getSecrets(context.Background())
}

func getParams(ctx context.Context) (string, string, error) {
    ssmClient, err := createSSMClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return "", "", err
    }

    param1, param2 := ssmClient.GetParams()
    ...
}


//constructor.go
func CreateClient(ctx context.Context) (SSMInterface, error) {
    ...
}
```

However, when testing main functions, I have to do something like this in each test:

```
//main_test.go
func TestMain() {
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            newSSMClient = MyMockConstructor()
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

It does not look good.

Is there a way to mock the constructor via an interface?

(I create a mock using mockery.)

Comment: What are you trying to check? Ask yourself whether mocking this factory function even makes sense.

Comment: `MyMockConstructor()` seems like a normal function, see [Is it possible to mock a function imported from a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42952191/is-it-possible-to-mock-a-function-imported-from-a-package/42952311#42952311)

Comment: Hi, @jub0bs thanks for your reply!
What if the main function is much more complex? Should I not test it?

Comment: Hi @icza!
This is exactly the approach I have. I thought this was a bad approach. Apparently not. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Not a big fan of @icza's suggestion. If you feel the need to mock a package-level function, it's a strong signal that this function should instead be a method.

Comment: @jub0bs There are cases when the used function aren't yours and you can't change them. Just think of the countless functions in the standard library. Sure, you can create a wrapper type and methods for them, but often the result is not necessarily simpler / cleaner.

Comment: @icza My main gripe is that the approach you suggests encourages global state, which is rarely a good idea. In particular, you have to worry about concurrent calls updating the same package-level function-valued variable. Also, you lose the advantage of package-level functions being (or [meant to be designed as](https://tip.golang.org/doc/comment#func)) concurrency-safe.