# Unit test mode identification in golang

Tags: go

I am building unit testing of the application that uses os.Exit(1), once os.Exit(1) executes remaining test file are skipped with go test, 
I am thinking about suppressing os.Exit during the unit test execution only. I wonder how I can determine that app has been bootstrap from go test runner?

Comment: In general, you're looking for "mocking" APIs.

Comment: Don't add your code in a comment; it's unreadable. Please edit your question and include it properly formatted.

Comment: Don't do that. Your code under test must work 100% the same under test as in production. Otherwise, you're doing an invalid test. If you have a function that exits during production, but not during test, then your code is not organized properly. Move the exit out of the code being tested, so that the tested code works identically in both test and prod environments.

Comment: @Flimzy  how do mean do not do that?  "Must" is very strong word, explain invalid, it is your opinion?

Comment: @AdrianWitas: If you want to test that a function works in production, you must (there is no other word) test it under the same meaningful conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will find various ways to unit test method with os.Exit() in "[Testing `os.Exit` scenarios in Go with coverage information (coveralls.io/Goveralls)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40615641/6309)".

It uses a function which is:

- `os.Exit()` when you are not testing

  ```
  var osExit = os.Exit
  ```
- and "yourOsExit" when you are testing.

  ```
  func TestCrasher(t *testing.T) {
      // Save current function and restore at the end:
      oldOsExit := osExit
      defer func() { osExit = oldOsExit }()
      osExit = myExit
  ```

Comment: Can you provide more details? If that link dies, this answer is effectively useless.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart done, but note that link points to another Stack Overflow question: it won't die/rot.

Comment: @VonC Okay. Why not vote to close this as a duplicate, then?

Comment: Various problem may be solved in a various way, the post asks specifically about unit test identification mode, so there is no duplication there, however  mocking OsExit might be one easier way to address it ,This solution has been applicable to other problems, thus post submitted.