# Which methodology i should use to test func main() in golang?

Tags: testing, go, program-entry-point

I have a function `main()` in main.go that does the job and all other functions are below it (I did not include them here). So, when I write tests for all `funcs` that are included in `main`, I can test them. But the code coverage is low because it shows that I did not cover code from my `main` func.

I know that there is a `TestMain` func in the testing library that should do the job, but I just cannot get how to get it to work so that the tests cover func `main()`.

Below is my `main()` func which is not covered by tests...

```
func main() {
    c, err := getConfig()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    slideshows, err := getSlideshows(c)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    displaySlideshows(slideshows)
}
```

Also, I did not find much about it on the Internet, so, if this is a stupid question, please, explain to me why this is such a dumb problem and where I should search for solutions!

Comment: `TestMain` has nothing to do with testing `main()`.

Comment: And if you have real functionality in main(), move it elsewhere to be easier to test, then have main call it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check out "[Go coverage with external tests](https://blog.cloudflare.com/go-coverage-with-external-tests/)", by **Filippo Valsorda**:

> We create a dummy test that executes `main()`, we put it behind a build tag, compile a binary with `go test -c -cover` and then run only that test instead of running the regular binary.
>
> Here's what the `rrdns_test.go` file looks like:

Note the empty line between the build tag and `package`:

> ```
> // +build testrunmain
>
> package main
>
> import "testing"
>
> func TestRunMain(t *testing.T) {
>     main()
> }
> ```
>
> We compile the binary like this:
>
> ```
> $ go test -coverpkg="rrdns/..." -c -tags testrunmain rrdns
> ```
>
> And then when we want to collect coverage information, we execute this instead of `./rrdns` (and run our test battery as usual):
>
> ```
> $ ./rrdns.test -test.run "^TestRunMain$" -test.coverprofile=system.out
> ```
>
> You must return from `main()` cleanly for the profile to be written to disk; in `RRDNS` we do that by catching `SIGINT`. You can still use command line arguments and standard input normally, just note that you will get two lines of extra output from the test framework.

This is similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39891957/6309) which proposes:

> ```
> func main() {
>     os.Exit(doFunc());
> }
> ```